# Почему элемент не переносится на новую строку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: rgba(47, 60, 255, 0.49);
}

.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #303f62;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  height: 125px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.left img {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.right {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

ul>a {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1e625b;
}

ul>a:hover {
  background: #29857d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.on {
  color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #303f62;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  min-height: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.links>a {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.links>a:hover {
  color: #00856b;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #e3ffa2;
  width: 80%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: red;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.content-line {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 250px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.content-line:first-child {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.section-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.section-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.break {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="about_us.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <div class="left">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" height="100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <ul>
          <a>Главная</a>
          <a class="on">О нас</a>
          <a>Контакты</a>
          <a>Партнеры</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>О нас</h1>
          <div style="margin-bottom: 50px" class="break"></div>
          <div class="content-line">
            <div class="section-left">
              <img src="images/img.jfif" height="200" alt="">
              <div class="text">Some text</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Почему элемент content-line не переносится на новую строку? Я расположил .break, но это почему-то не сработало: элементы h1 и .content-line расположены на одной той же строке. В чем проблема? Как это исправить?

Comment: Я разобрался в чем дело. Нужно добавить элементу .content свойство flex-wrap: wrap. Теперь все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение**
Я разобрался в чем дело. Нужно добавить элементу .content свойство flex-wrap: wrap. Теперь все работает